# Handle nested promises in cloud functions

Tags: node.js, typescript, promise, async-await, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new in writing typescript with async-await but I retrieved all discounts, check if active or expired, if expired get all discount products then print its id's on the response, the problem I can't handle nested promises and get ids of discounted products to display in response

```
exports.terminateDiscount = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const discountSnapshots = await admin.firestore().collection("Discounts").get();
        const promises = [];
        const today = Date.now();
        discountSnapshots.forEach(async discountSnapshot => {
            const startDate = +discountSnapshot.data().startDate.toMillis();
            const endDate = discountSnapshot.data().endDate;
            if (today > startDate && endDate !== null && today > endDate.toMillis()) { // discount expired
                promises.push(discountSnapshot.id); // print discount id only
                const discountProducts=await admin.firestore().collection("Products").where("discountId", "==", discountSnapshot.id).get();
                discountProducts.forEach(product => {
                     promises.push(product.id); // products id's not added in promises :(
                });
            }
        });
        res.send(await Promise.all(promises));
    } catch (error) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's so hard to use `async/await` with `.forEach`. In simple, `.forEach` calls a callback with each item of array, and it always is a `sync` process. This mean, you will never wait until `const discountProducts = await admin.firestore()...` finish, you return immediate after call `discountSnapshots.forEach...`.

`Promise.all` just working fine if you give it a promises array, in your code, you pass a strings arrays (I think `discountSnapshot.id` is a string) to `Promise.all`, in this case it will return "original" input - strings array.

I suggest use `Array.map` in this case, `.map` function returns a array, we make it to return a promises array, then just wait until all of promises finish.

```
exports.terminateDiscount = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const discountSnapshots = await admin.firestore().collection("Discounts").get();
    const today = Date.now();

    const ids = []; // to store discount id or products id or both ????

    const promises = discountSnapshots.docs.map(async (discountSnapshot) => {
      const startDate = +discountSnapshot.data().startDate.toMillis();
      const endDate = discountSnapshot.data().endDate;
      if (today > startDate && endDate !== null && today > endDate.toMillis()) { // discount expired
        ids.push(discountSnapshot.id); // print discount id only ???
        const discountProducts = await admin.firestore().collection("Products").where("discountId", "==", discountSnapshot.id).get();
        discountProducts.forEach(product => {
          ids.push(product.id); // products id's ??? "print discount id only"
        });
      }
    });
    await Promise.all(promises); // wait until we fill the ids array, the ids has been filled.

    res.send(ids);
  } catch (error) {
  }
});
```

Comment: gave me this error, Property 'map' does not exist on type 'QuerySnapshot'.

Comment: @AhmedAbdElfattah I updated my answer. `discountSnapshots.docs.map` instead of `discountSnapshots.map`

Comment: How would this work when there's no return statement in the .map() callback? Why `await Promise.all(ids)` when `ids` is an array of values, not Promises?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 If you not return anythings in map's callback, `undefined` will be return as a default value, in this case, type of return value is `Promise<void>`. Yes, you are right, we only need `res.send(ids);`, thank for point that.

Comment: If `promises` is an array of undefineds, then why `await(Promise.all(promises))`.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I will try again with a sample, what is your typescript version? Try run this example on your environment, `console.log([1, 2, 3].map(async () => {}))`

Comment: In this case, callback of `.map` function always return return a Promise, because `async` has been used. Then `promises` will store some item like `Promise {<resolved>: undefined}` , Here, we just need to wait until the task in `.map` finish, not need to get back the value of the task.

Comment: I don't run typesript, just javascript.

Comment: Code should actually work. What I'm driving at is that by returning a promise from the `.map()` callback, you have the opportunity of delivering data down the promise chain and you can avoid the ugly outer member `ids`. You will need to flatten an array of arrays of results though.